# how to get value from a custom dialog box to the main activity in android app

Tags: android, customdialog

in my activity when the user clicks a textview a custom dialog box is opened. Here i have set some wheel pickers. The value which the user sets in the wheel picker is been shown as a title in the custom dialog box. When the user clicks the Ok button the dialog box closes and i want the that title text to be displayed in my main activity's text view.

I know that we can set initialize a variable in our activity class and set it's value in dialog box, nothing special. But i have written the Custom dialog box as a separate class file
as follows

```
bd = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        bd.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
        {   
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(main.this);
                customizeDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

How to get the value from that class to my main activity class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way, in my main activity i have assigned the TextView as

```
public static TextView bd;
```

In my CustomizeDialog class when i initialized a variable as follow

`static String bdDate;`

When i click the Ok button to close the the Custom Dialog, i have written as

```
close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {  
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                  if (v == close)
                  bdDate = wheelMenu3[getWheel(R.id.p3).getCurrentItem()];
                  main.bd.setText(bdDate);
                  dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an handler in your Activity and pass it to your dialog that will do the job. Something like below

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler()
{
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg)
    {
        super.handleMessage(msg);

        switch (msg.what)
        {
        case 1:
            // Do some stuff
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now pass this handler object

```
CustomizeDialog customizeDialog = new CustomizeDialog(main.this, mHandler);
customizeDialog.show();
```

When you want set some value send it using this handler object